# Installing JOGL on a mac to run in Terminal

Tags: java, macos, opengl, jogl

I am having difficulty running JOGL on my mac. I am running Mac OSX 10.8.5. I followed the instructions given here:

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Compile_and_run_your_project_from_the_command_line

First I downloaded jogamp-all-platforms.7z.

I copied the mac jogl jar files to /jogl2/jar, and I copied the contents of the lib folder to /jogl2/lib.

I copied gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar to /Library/Java/Extensions.

I then compiled a simple class with:

```
$ javac -classpath "/jogl2/jar/gluegen-rt.jar:/jogl2/jar/jogl-all.jar" /COM/Week1/JOGLtutorial/S1.java
```

It compiles with no errors. When trying to run the compiled program I get the following error:

```
$ java -classpath "/jogl2/jar/gluegen-rt.jar:/jogl2/jar/jogl-all.jar" -Djava.library.path="/jogl2/lib" /COM/Week1/JOGLtutorial/S1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /COM/Week1/JOGLtutorial/S1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .COM.Week1.JOGLtutorial.S1
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Could anyone enlighten me on my errors? I have it working fine on windows. I think the problem is something to do with incorrectly setting up environment variables.

Comment: see if there is an S1.class file in /COM/Week1/JOGLtutorial/

Comment: @RayTayek Yep, after compiling, the class file is there.

Comment: try adding "." (current directory) to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem. Sorry for the late reply @RayTayek.

Comment: Sorry, you shouldn't need to put anything into the "lib" directory. Setting the Java library path is no longer mandatory with JOGL 2.